# When changing profile picture, the current picture is loaded via HTTP

Tags: bug, profile-page, hyperlinks, profile-picture, ssl

When changing profile picture, a request is made to `/users/popup/change-picture/<user-id>`, which returns HTML displayed in a popup. This HTML contains an `<img>` tag with an HTTP link, for example:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ik31.png?s=128&g=1?s=42&g=1" />
```

It should be changed to HTTPS.